# Is it possible to trace queries that never complete with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, profiler, extended-events

Running SQL Server 2008 R2.  We have some queries that typically take less than one second to complete, but, occasionally, they are taking longer than 30 seconds which causes a client timeout.

Unfortunately, these queries are not showing up in our slow query trace because there is no sp_statement_completed or sql_statement_completed event -- it seems they are not completing on the server side.

Is there a way, preferably using extended events, to trace queries that start, but never complete?  I don't want to trace everything and generate a huge amount of logs because this is something I want to leave running for a while since the problem is so intermittent.

**Update**

I just noticed [Event Pairing targets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630339(v=sql.105).aspx#PairingTarget) which I think could work.  If I read correctly, it would capture any start event that doesn't have a matching end event.  Before I mark that as an answer, does anyone have experience tracking this?  Is there a lot of overhead?

Comment: In server side trace, you can use `User Error Message Event` with filter on `error <> 0, error <> 1, severity <> 10`. Also Grant blogged about using Event Paring to find out application timeout [here](http://www.scarydba.com/2015/03/12/monitoring-timeouts/). Hope that helps you.

Comment: I knew someone had written about using XEvents to do it, just couldn't remember.

Comment: @Kin upvote for Grant's post. I was coming here to link to that!

Comment: This is good stuff.  One thing I forgot to ask is how to get other relevant information when this timeout happens.  I already know the timeout happened from my SQLException in the application logs, but I need to find out what other stuff was running at that time...a sort of snapshot of the server during that time period.  Almost like an sp_who for the duration of the running query.  Is that possible?