# Can SQL Server 2008 R2 extended events execute stored procedure or query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, extended-events

I'm trying to use extended events to track queries that never complete using Event Pairing as a target.  (see this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97028/is-it-possible-to-trace-queries-that-never-complete-with-sql-server-2008-r2) I asked a few days ago).  The event pairing target should let me find queries that started but never completed.

My new problem is that I need to know what else was happening on the server when this event happens.  I'd like to execute a stored procedure like sp_who, sp_who2, sp_WhoIsActive, etc. whenever I find a query that has not completed in 20+ seconds, for example.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box, no.

You'd need to hook into the event stream for extended events and then take action based on that. Tom Stringer has a [good overview and sample code](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913084854/http://tstringer.azurewebsites.net/?p=821) to do this!

See also [Introducing the Extended Events Reader](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/extended_events/2011/07/20/introducing-the-extended-events-reader/) by Mike Wachal.

Jonathan Kehayias also describes it in detail in his [Pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sqlserver-advanced-xevents).